# TextBox - how to get an event when inserted into the text using Drag&Drop?

Tags: wpf, textbox, drag-and-drop

WPF TextBox - how to get an event when inserted into the text using Drag&Drop?
I drag text from the Browser.
And I want to understand when pasted the text that it was just Drag&Drop.

p.s OnDrop Event is not fired

Comment: As far as i know, only `TextChanged` event will get fired

Comment: Use the PreviewDragEnter and PreviewDragDrop events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `PreviewDrop` event to notified in case text is dropped on it:

```
<TextBox PreviewDrop="TextBox_PreviewDrop"/>
```